# Prevent a file from overwrite after typing cat > file command

Tags: linux, file

Let's say I've a file `SO.txt` with some content and I accidentally typed `cat > SO.txt`

Is there a way to prevent the contents of the file from being overwritten?

```
$cat SO.txt 
$Hello, Stack Overflow!
$cat > SO.txt
<<DO SOMETHING HERE TO PREVENT OVERWRITING>>
```

Comment: I don't get it, do you want to recover or to prevent?

Comment: @MiguelOrtiz - I've updated the question. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the file has been overwritten it is not possible to recover it.

To prevent from overwriting a particular file you need to remove write permissions from it using `chmod`:

```
$ touch foo
$ chmod a-w foo
$ cat > foo
bash: foo: Permission denied
```

Comment: I'm confused because the title says "recover" and description "prevent"...

Comment: This still overwrites the file.

Comment: @Learner What do you mean?

Comment: @hek2mgl - I mean changing permissions after typing `cat > SO.txt` overwrites the file.

Comment: If you executed `cat > SO.txt` already then the file *has been overwritten* already. Nothing in life can *prevent* from things which *happened* in the past. If you ask *How to recover a file after it has been overwritten*, then no, there is no reliable chance to do that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the confirmation. Will add `cat >` to one of my dangerous commands list. :)

Comment: I shall accept this as answer, if you could update your post accordingly.

Comment: This is not related to `cat`. It is related to `>` which is output redirection performed by the *shell*.

Comment: You should specify this: chmod oug-w SO.txt
In babun I discovered "-w" isn't enough to remove succesfully all the writting permissions.

Comment: @MiguelOrtiz Seems that `-w` works with chmod from GNU coreutils but it is not specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html). But you can use `a-w` instead of `oug-w`.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` has

`set -o noclobber`

> If  the  redirection operator is `>`, and the `noclobber` option to the `set`
>   builtin has been enabled, the redirection will fail if the  file  whose
>   name  results  from the expansion of word exists and is a regular file.

To recover the file (you didn't ask, but you tagged it "recovery"), you need to go to your backups.